# Ito representation of $W(T)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I want to find Ito representation for variable $X = W(T)$, where $W$ is a Wiener process.

Let $W_{t}$ be a Wiener process on a standard filtered probability space $(\Omega ,{\mathcal {F}},{\mathcal {F}}_{t},P)$ and let ${\mathcal {G}}_{t}$ be the augmented filtration generated by $B$. If $X$ is a square integrable random variable measurable with respect to ${\mathcal {G}}_{\infty }$, then there exists a predictable process $\Theta$ which is adapted with respect to ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {G}}_{t}}$, such that

$$X = E[X] + \int_0^T\Theta_sdWs$$

I found somewhere on internet that solution to this problem is $W[T] = \int_0^TdWs$, however I'm not sure exactly what it means. Does it mean that this expression equals to $\Theta_s$ ? Could you please explain to me why this formula is proper for Ito representation ?

Comment: What is $\Theta_s$?

Comment: I updated my question to be as formal as possible ;))

Comment: It simply means that the desired equation is true with $\Theta_s = 1$.

Comment: I see, but why then $E[\int_0^T dWs] = 0 $ ?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're asking.  You know the definition of the Ito integral $\int_0^T \Theta_s \,dW_s$, right?  Apply it with $\Theta_s$ being the constant process $1$ (it doesn't depend on either $s$ or $\omega$) and verify that in this case you get $\int_0^T \Theta_s\,dW_s = W_T$.  So the Ito representation of $X = W_T$ is $W_T = E[W_T] + \int_0^T \Theta_s\,dW_s$ where $\Theta_s = 1$ (noting $E[W_T] = 0$).

Comment: Do you mean $T$ here to be a constant time, or a stopping time?

Comment: I consider T as constant time

Comment: Okay, then all is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply the statement that when you compute the Ito integral $\int_0^T \Theta_s\,dW_s$ with $\Theta_s$ being the constant process $1$ (not depending on either $s$ or $\omega$), you get $\int_0^T 1\,dW_s = W_T$.  (This is an easy exercise that can be done directly from the definition of the Ito integral.)

Combining this with the fact that $E[W_T] = 0$ (from the definition of Brownian motion as a mean-zero Gaussian process), we see that
$$W_T = E[W_T] + \int_0^T 1\,dW_s$$
and so this is the Ito representation of $W_T$.  The notation $\int_0^T \,dW_s$ is just shorthand for $\int_0^T 1\,dW_s$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Everything is understable ;))